# Clarification of matrix superscript and subscript indexes notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors

I came across a matrixes that have indexes written as $\textbf{A}_{ij}$, $\textbf{A}^{ij}$, $\textbf{A}^{i}_{j}$ or even $\textbf{A}^{(i)}_{j}$.

What does each of these notations means and how to distinguish the superscript indexes with matrix exponents?

Comment: In Einstein's summation convention, the superscript is usually used to represent the number of rows of the matrix, and the subscript is used to represent the number of columns of the matrix.

In fact, the superscript is usually used to represent the contravariant functor, and the subscript is usually used to represent the covariant functor

Answer (score 0):

Usually $A_{ij}$ means the element in row $i$ and column $j$ of the matrix $A$.
$A^{ij}$ is quite confusing.
Sometimes you can also use the subscript to indicate the rows and the superscript to indicate the column, in that case $A_j^i$ indicates the element in row $j$ and column $i$ of the matrix $A$.

But it's just a matter of convention, the important is to define the notation before introducing formulas.

Answer (score 0):

In a context where multiple of these notations appear, I would expect $\mathbf{A}_{ij}$, $\mathbf{A}^{ij}$ and $\mathbf{A}^i_j$ to mean respectively elements of $V \otimes V$, $V^* \otimes V^*$ and $V^* \otimes V \cong \operatorname{End}(V)$ respectively, where $V$ is some vector space and $V^*$ is its dual. Not sure what $\mathbf{A}_j^{(i)}$ should be without more context.